# DB2 group by with NULL SQL Error [22007]

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have query with data format. I try to convert it into an integer, but it doesn't help me, I can't group by because I have NULL in rows.

```
SELECT t."Reception Date", CASE WHEN t."DT" IS NULL THEN 100
                                ELSE 100500
                           END AS "GG" 
FROM fit t
GROUP BY t."Reception Date", CASE WHEN t."DT" IS NULL THEN 100
                                  ELSE 100500
                             END
```

I have many rows so I want to group it, but got error

> SQL Error [22007]: [SQL0181] Value in date, time, or timestamp string
>   not valid.   java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0181] Value in date, time, or
>   timestamp string not valid.

```
Reception Date  GG
20160921        100500
20160921        0
```

*SAMPLE DATA:*

```
create table qtemp/fit
(
    "Reception Date" char(10),
    "DT" int
);

insert into qtemp/fit values
('20160921', 140816),
('20160921', 250816),
('20160921', 180816),
('20160921', 70916),
('20160921', 10916),
('20160921', 210916),
('20160921', 210916),
('20160921', 210916),
('20160921', 200916),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 210916)
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and it's expected result. It's very unclear as it is now.

Comment: |Reception Date |GG     |
|---------------|-------|
|20160921       |100500 |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |0      |
|20160921       |100500 |

Comment: Please, edit the question instead.

Comment: If base   SELECT t."Reception Date", t."DT" 
  FROM fit t Reception Date |DT     |
---------------|-------|
20160921       |140816 |
20160921       |250816 |
20160921       |180816 |
20160921       |70916  |
20160921       |10916  |
20160921       |210916 |
20160921       |210916 |
20160921       |210916 |
20160921       |200916 |
20160921       |0      |
20160921       |0      |
20160921       |0      |
20160921       |0      |
20160921       |0      |
20160921       |210916 |

Comment: could you provide table ddl?

Comment: I don't think the statement you've shown can produce that error.

Comment: Your data samples do not show NULLs (but zeros) and does not show valid date or timestamp formats.

Comment: Update the OP to remove the sqlcode\sqlstate error that does not reflect an issue for the query currently presented, **or** update the OP to include the expression that does not properly convert the [apparently] character string values to DATE data-type values; a reader can then know what needs to be corrected to resolve that error. Give the actual DDL and SELECT query; i.e. if what others have provided in edits is not actual\representative, then make corrections. NB, the NULL value can be grouped and will result in an expression evaluating to NULL, so NULL values should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

**With Sample Date (Assumed):**

```
create table qtemp/tstdta 
(
    "Reception Date" char(10),
    "DT" int
);

insert into qtemp/tstdta values
('20160921', 140816),
('20160921', 250816),
('20160921', 180816),
('20160921', 70916),
('20160921', 10916),
('20160921', 210916),
('20160921', 210916),
('20160921', 210916),
('20160921', 200916),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', 0),
('20160921', null),
('20160921', null),
('20160921', null)
```

**Solution:**

```
WITH as t (
    SELECT "Reception Date",
          CASE WHEN "DT" IS NULL THEN 100
               ELSE 100500
               END AS "GG"
     FROM qtemp/tstdta
) 
SELECT "Reception Date", "GG", count(*) as COUNT
FROM t
GROUP BY "Reception Date", "GG"
```

**Result:**

```
 Reception Date  GG           COUNT        
 ------------------------------------------
 20160921        100          3             
 20160921        100500       14
```